# Remove padding in Bootstrap Col without letting the image enlarge

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a col-4 | col-8 layout in Bootstrap 4 Beta 3.
The first col contains a pic, the second col should contain a pic and text aside.

At the moment I have divided the second col into another row with two cols.
I need to have these to cols stick together (e.g. class=no-gutters). But the image inside gets larger than the one in the first col as soon as I remove the gutters. I cannot remove all gutters on all three cols, as there should be a margin remaining between main col 1 and 2.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/SchweizerSchoggi/pen/mpjgLP

```
<div class="container mt-3">

  <div class="row">

    <!-- Teaser 1 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4" id="teaser_Umzug">

      <div class="teaser-img teaser-stick">

        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" alt="Bild XY Company Umzug" class="img-fluid z-1 mr-1" />

        <div class="teaser-overlay pt-2 pl-4 z-2">
          <div class="teaser-txt">
            <h2 class="mb-3"></h2>
            <p class="mb-4">
              <span class="bold clearfix">Settelen &ndash;</span> ist Ihr Partner<br/>für <a href="#">regionalen</a> und <a href="#">nationalen</a> Umzug.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="teaser">Mehr erfahren</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Teaser 2 -->
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8" id="teaser_AutoService">

      <div class="row">

        <!-- Teaser 2 Img -->  
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-box-light">
             <div class="ml-0 mr-0"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" alt="Bild XY Company Auto und Service" class="img-fluid" /></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Teaser 2 Text -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-box-light">
          <div class="teaser-txt pt-4 pl-4">
            <p class="mb-4">
              <span class="bold clearfix">XY Company &ndash;</span> Ihr starker Partner in Sachen <a href="#">Auto</a> und <a href="#">Service</a>.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="teaser">Services</button>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It's still not perfectly clear what is it that you actually want. Ignore the columns etc. for a minute and say in plain English: What is the height of both images you want to end up with? Both images equal height? And what about the relationship of the image on the left and the overall height of the grey box on the right? Please clarify.

Comment: Let's say these are 3 Cols. Col 1 is standalone (only the pic), Col 2 and 3 should stick together. The pic in Col 1 and 2 should have the same height, as well as Col 3 (the grey box). My problem is, that I need to remove the padding-left and the padding-right from Col 2. And as soon as I try this, the img inside that Col 2 enlarges. This should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a solution I came up with...

Add the `pl-md-0` class to the column for the teaser 2 image. (that removes the left padding for medium screens)

Then put the contents of the first column (that includes the teaser 1 image) into a new row-column pair.

Then add the `pl-md-0` class to the inner column for the teaser 1 image.

I believe this is the effect you were going for. (I didn't touch the right paddings because I thought it wasn't necessary but you certainly could remove both the left and right paddings with the `px-md-0` class.)

Here's the code:

```css
.bg-box-light {
            background-color: #eee; /* TBD ! */
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Teaser 1 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4" id="teaser_Umzug">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col pl-md-0">
                <div class="teaser-img teaser-stick">
                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" alt="Bild XY Company Umzug" class="img-fluid z-1 mr-1" />

                    <div class="teaser-overlay pt-2 pl-4 z-2">
                        <div class="teaser-txt">
                            <h2 class="mb-3"></h2>
                            <p class="mb-4">
                                <span class="bold clearfix">Settelen &ndash;</span> ist Ihr Partner<br/>für <a href="#">regionalen</a> und <a href="#">nationalen</a> Umzug.
                            </p>
                            <button type="button" class="teaser">Mehr erfahren</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Teaser 2 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8" id="teaser_AutoService">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Teaser 2 Img -->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pl-md-0 bg-box-light">
                    <div class="ml-0 mr-0"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" alt="Bild XY Company Auto und Service" class="img-fluid" /></div>
                </div>

                <!-- Teaser 2 Text -->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-box-light">
                    <div class="teaser-txt pt-4 pl-4">
                        <p class="mb-4">
                            <span class="bold clearfix">XY Company &ndash;</span> Ihr starker Partner in Sachen <a href="#">Auto</a> und <a href="#">Service</a>.
                        </p>
                        <button type="button" class="teaser">Services</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it's not 100% the result I was looking for, but it solved my problem with the image, that got bigger every time I removed the padding from col-2 ... I will be able to finish it from here on.. Great help, thank you!